# What should I do when I get the excessive memory usage error when sorting in mongodb when I already have indexes created for the field in question?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, query-optimization, mongodb-indexes

The following error: "The sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM."
I have a find() that returns more than 9,000 records and I need to sort them by a nested field with 4 levels:
array -> id -> id -> string
'items.xxx_id.xxx_id.name'
I know it is possible to increase the total memory that can be used, but is there another way? Or testing whether the index is actually working.
I tried increasing the memory to 64 MB and that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you created an index on the field that your are sorting on? What's the full query and the associated `.explain()` output? Also consider upgrading as the default limit was raised a while back

Comment: Yes, the index was created, but it didn't work. The query was just all records from the collections with "Done" state, so about 9100 records and then sorts by 'items.xxx_id.xxx_id.name'. I updated the default size limit just for this test. Now I'm with the server here (it has really outdated versions), to update the OS, mongo versions, etc (it's with the mongodb 4.0 community).